# SQLiteDatabase.execSQL not working as expected for INSERT INTO query

Tags: android, sqlite

I am porting iOS code that works perfectly to the Android OS.  I perform a bunch of queries, inserting the results of the queries into a temporary table.  When all of the queries are complete I then grab all of the results from the temporary table into a collection of objects of my own creation.  I am using a temporary table rather than selecting straight into the collection because I believe it executes more quickly, or at least it does on the iOS side anyways.  My problem is that execSQL() is not working as I would expect, here is the code:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE SearchResults(Name text);");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO SearchResults (Name) SELECT Name FROM ProductNames WHERE NameLower MATCH '" + termLowerCase + "*';");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO SearchResults (Name) SELECT Name FROM BrandNames WHERE NameLower MATCH '" + termLowerCase + "*';");
```

When I execute this code I only ever get one row from the first execSQL() call with the INSERT.  I know there are more than one result in the ProductNames table that should match my term, and I know there are hundreds of rows in the BrandNames table that should match my term.  If I change the code to this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT Name FROM ProductNames WHERE NameLower MATCH '" + termLowerCase + "*'", null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
{
    resultSet.add(cursor.getString(0));
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
cursor.close();
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT Name FROM BrandNames WHERE NameLower MATCH '" + termLowerCase + "*'", null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
{
    resultSet.add(cursor.getString(0));
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

I get all the results that I'm expecting.

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Am I using execSQL() in an inappropriate way?  I assumed it would simply pass the query onto sqlite3_exec() which is what I use on iOS.  If I am using execSQL() inappropriately what are its limitations and what is the fastest alternative to what I want to do?  Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `SQLiteDatabase` documentation you can not use [execSQL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) in this case. Try doing that statement with rawQuery instead.

Comment: I believe the documentation indicates don't use it if you need data returned from the query.  Using rawQuery doesn't seem feasible in my scenario, the above raw query code takes an extremely long amount of time to run on my ADP2.  Also of note, I have tested porting over some other queries of mine from the iOS version in a separate method that also use INSERT INTO with a SELECT using fts3 MATCH and these seem to be working fine.  This problem remains a mystery.

Comment: The way I understand the documentation says that it will run ONE statement that is NOT a SELECT. Meaning, INSERT + SELECT violates both constraints of that documentation. Does it work when you use rawQuery? While slow, consider the operation you're doing over the size of your data. It's not a trivial operation.

Comment: Yes I get what you're saying here, however I do have working execSQL() calls with INSERT INTO and SELECT statements in the query.  Here's an example of one that works:
    sql = "INSERT INTO SearchResults (SearchOrder, PID, ProductName, DBTable) " +
         "SELECT 3, P.ProductID, P.Name, 0 " +
         "FROM Ingredients I " +
         "INNER JOIN ProductAltNames A ON (I.IngredientsID = A.IngredientID) " +
         "INNER JOIN ProductNames P ON (A.ProductID = P.ProductID) " +
         "WHERE I.DescriptionLower MATCH '" + termLowerCase + "*'";
    db.execSQL(sql);